# Why is not recognizing the complete URL in Python-Bottle Restful

Tags: python, shell, bottle

I'm doing an update to MongoDB using Bottle on Python. I'm trying to get two parameters from the url, but only can read one. I check the url and it's not complete. I'm sending:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/update?id="10011-2017-TEST"&result="Violation%20Issued"
```

But server throws

```
GET curl http://localhost:8080/update?id="10011-2017-TEST"
```

```py
@route('/update', method='GET')
def update_data():
    print("URL"  + request.url)
```

The url shows:

```
http://localhost:8080/update?id="10011-2017-TEST"
```

this is why I'm not getting the second parameter. I need to send the parameter in this way:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/update?id="10011-2017-TEST"&result="Violation%20Issued"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not Bottle or your webserver; it's how you're using quotes on the command line.

You need quote your call this way:

```
curl "http://localhost:8080/update?id=10011-2017-TEST&result=Violation%20Issued"
```

The "&" has special meaning to most shells (e.g. bash), including yours.
When you called it the way you were, the shell was [interpreting the unquoted ampersand](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86247/what-does-ampersand-mean-at-the-end-of-a-shell-script-line) (&) as "this the end of my command, and please run it in it the background." (In fact, I'm surprised that you did not also see a message like `Unknown command: result=Violation%20Issued`)

So your `curl` call was in fact equivalent to just:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/update?id=10011-2017-TEST
```

which is consistent with what you saw at your server.

Read up on [how to quote command lines](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Quoting) for more details.